# creating a composite variable in piecewiseSEM for structural equation modelling in R

Tags: r, composite, piecewise, structural-equation-model

I am trying to create a composite variable to use in an SEM using piecewiseSEM. I've read this [book](https://jslefche.github.io/sem_book/composite-variables.html) but I still have two questions that I was hoping someone could help me with:

```
#create dummy data where Z is my response variable and X and Y are the indicators I want as a composite variable
set.seed(111)
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(100), group = rep(letters[1:2], each = 50))
dat$y <- dat$x + runif(100)
dat$z <- dat$y + runif(100)

#run a very simple model
model1<-lm(z~x+y,data=dat)

#run a model that fits data better than model1
model2<-lme(z~x+y,random=(1|group)

#check coefficients
summary(model1)
```

1. when extracting the coefficients of each indicator, do I use a full mixed effect model or a simple quick and dirty model (model1). in otherwords, should I go through the model selection process as if it were my final regression? (model2).
2. from the summary of the model, if an indicator is not significant, do I remove it or still use it? for example, if x would not have had a significant effect on z, does this mean it should not be included in the composite variable?

thanks in advance!